# Compact manifolds which do not admit a diffeomorphism with a dense orbit

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems

What is an example of a compact manifold which does not admit a diffeomorphism with at least one dense orbit?

Moreover, is it true to say that every isometry of $\mathbb{C}P^n$ with the Fubini-Study metric do not possess any dense orbit?

Comment: No isometry of $\mathbb{CP}^n$ has a dense orbit, because the square of such an isometry is holomorphic and so can be regarded as an element of the compact Lie group  $\mathrm{SU}(n{+}1)$ and hence is congugate to an element of the maximal torus, and no element of a maximal torus can have a dense orbit because it has to preserve a transverse collection of hyperplanes and so perserve the distances from these hyperplanes.  A little more work takes care of the case of an anti-holomorphic isometry.

Comment: For $C^1$ diffeomorphisms preserving volume, there is a residual set which is transitive (having a dense orbit). See Theorem 1.3 of https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2090361   So in some sense such diffeomorphisms are "generic". See also the comments after the statement of the theorem about the homeomorphism case.

Comment: @RobertBryant  Thank you very much  for your answer. I try to understand its detail for $n>1$. My motivation was $S^2$ whose all isometries are non ergodic maps.

Comment: My apology, I correct: The isometries are ergodic and without dense orbit.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dolgopyat and Pesin proved ([ETDS 2002](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0143385702000202)) that "every compact manifold of dimension $\geq 2$ admits a Bernoulli diffeomorphism with non-zero Lyapunov exponents".  That is, on any such manifold $M$ there is a $C^\infty$ diffeomorphism $f$ that preserves volume $m$ and has the property that $(M,m,f)$ is a measure-preserving transformation that is measure-theoretically isomorphic to a Bernoulli shift.  In particular, by the Birkhoff ergodic theorem, $m$-a.e. point $x\in M$ has the property that its orbit equidistributes with respect to $m$, meaning that for every continuous $\phi\colon M\to \mathbb{R}$, we have $\frac 1n \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \phi(f^kx) \to \int \phi\,dm$ as $n\to\infty$.  In particular, any such $x$ has a dense orbit.